# How can I profile `require` statements in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, require

I'm interested in seeing how long (in seconds) each `require` statement in my Ruby code takes to load. How can I temporarily override that method and print out some logging information for slow loads?

Answer (score -1):

You can override `Kernel.require` like this:

```rb
module Kernel
  # make an alias of the original require
  alias_method :original_require, :require

  # rewrite require
  def require name
    start = Time.now

    # code to time
    ret = original_require name

    finish = Time.now
    diff = finish - start

    # TODO: This should really add up all of
    # the require calls for a certain module
    if diff > 0.1
      puts "#{diff} #{name}"
    end
    ret
  end
end
```